# How to align overflown div to right?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using Bootstrap carousel to build a "timeline" widget. Each square represents one month, from left (older) to right (newer). The sliders buttons are working fine, but I want it to start aligned to the right, i.e., showing the most recent month. If the user wants to see older months then he will need to use the buttons.

Here's a fiddle simulating the widget (http://www.bootply.com/ni9PtghiK5). How can I achieve it? I couldn't use `float: right;` to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the following CSS property: `direction: rtl;` on `.carousel-inner`

Comment: I had to reverse the order of the elements inside, because that make it starts from the right. But it did what I needed!